# Reasonable reference index or list of the interpretability/consistency hierarchy

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, proof-theory

In Kanamori's [*The Higher Infinite*](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540888666) a diagram is included towards the end of the book which illustrates the large cardinal hierarchy by listing many large cardinal axioms and drawing their direction implications/relative consistency implications.

I am wondering if there is anywhere available a similar diagram, or maybe even preferably a list, dealing with the interpretability/consistency hierarchy (here I am assuming them both to be equivalent, which I believe just limits it to theories that are reflexive and conservative over $\Pi^0_1$ sentences, correct?).

Of course, such a list could easily be arbitrarily long ($T < T+Con(T)< etc.$) and it could also be arbitrarily short ($PRA < PA < Z_2 < ZFC$). I guess what I am looking for is something that does list many of the useful or well studied fragments of $PA$, fragments of $Z_2$, and fragments of $ZFC$ without falling victim to arbitrary sequences of direct assumptions of consistency. Things like Presburger arithmetic, $Q$, $I\Delta_0 + EXP$, the big five of reverse mathematics, $KP$ set theory, are what I am looking for.

My main motivation for asking this question is that I very often have seen answers to questions here or elsewhere that involved to me less familiar fragments of $PA$ or $Z_2$ and not known where to look them up or where their place is in the, I guess, larger reverse mathematics program (Simpson's [Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/subsystems-of-second-order-arithmetic/EA16CB4305831530B7015D6BC46B7424) was often but not always helpful, and there, as far as I'm aware, is not such list or diagram of the systems discussed).  I have a vague memory that there existed a list that was along these lines in a paper on ordinal analysis; I thought that it was written by Rathjen, however I reviewed many of his papers looking for it and was unable to find what I thought I recalled.

A list, a diagram, or even an article or book which contains the information I am looking for would be a satisfactory answer.

Comment: A table of the sort you are looking for can be found on pages 39-40 of Harvey Friedman's paper "Interpretations according to Tarski,: available at the link https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/1/1952/files/2014/01/Tarski1052407-13do0b2.pdf

Comment: @AliEnayat that is exactly the paper I thought I remembered seeing, thank you.